# Too low bandwith in RAM benchmark

Tags: memory, performance, benchmarking, memtest86+, memtest

I'd like to ask for help in interpretation of Memtest benchmark. I have **G.SKILL 16GB (2x8GB) 3200MHz CL16 Ripjaws V Black.** I've done some benchmarking and here's a result. It's showing under 16000MB/s but in product description there is 3200 MHz (PC4-25600). Is it too low in that case?

MB: MSI MAG B550 TOMAHAWK
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600

[image: screen of results]

Comment: Just because your memory supports 3200 MHz it doesn’t mean your system does, you have provided us absolutely, no information about your motherboard

Comment: Thanks for remark, It's MSI MAG B550 TOMAHAWK.

Comment: You should always edit your question instead of submitting a comment.  Have you enabled the appropriate A-XMP to get the performance you want out of your memory you want?

Comment: I've made edit a the same time. No I didn't change anything in the config. Is that graph showing to low bandwidth than could be in my setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to the comments first, your board supports the RAM.
Based on some bit calculations using standard models of MHz to Mb/s, it looks like your RAM seems to be running fine. There are some small parts of RAM that aren't used. For example, I have 16GB of RAM in one computer, and it uses around 15.8 of it, just like your graph shows.
TL;DR: Your RAM is doing perfectly fine. No worries.

Comment: That's great, thank you!